# Read 16bit byte array into integers without truncation

Tags: python, wav, esp32, micropython

I've got an I2S microphone connected to a microcontroller and have managed to dump 16-bit audio WAV audio to a python bytearray object that looks like this (using a [micropython library](https://github.com/miketeachman/micropython-esp32-i2s-examples/tree/master/examples)):

```
raw = bytearray(b"\xac\xffW\x00\xfc\xfe\xac\xffs\xfe\xfc\xfe+\xfes\xfe7\xfe+\xfe\x8c\xfe7\xfe\x1f\xff\x8c\xfe\xcf\xff\x1f\xfft\x00\xcf\xff\xfb\x00t\x00?\x01\xfb...")
```

I have successfully written these bytearray dumps to a file I created like this:

```
wav = open('16bitaudio.wav','wb')
#....some code to write the wav header
wav.write(raw)
wav.close()
```

When I open this on my PC it plays the samples I've recorded faithfully, sounds great.

My issue comes - I want to translate this data to an integer which represents the average intensity of sound in my samples. I first attempted to do this:

```
intensity = sum(raw)/count(raw)
```

However, this tends to result in a number ~128 almost all the time - suggesting to me it's being read as random bytes. Upon further investigation, these array functions seem to assume that we've only got an 8 bit byte (reading the value b'\xffW' which I believe is a little endian 22527):

```
>>> int(raw[1])
255
```

which appears to be just the b'\xff' part.

I can get my expected value by parsing just the byte manyally into int.from_bytes:

```
>>> int.from_bytes(b'\xffW','little')
22527
```

However I can't seem to iterate through the bytearray without it truncating to 8-bit.

Finally, I have read the struct.unpack methods - which look OK, but I'm not sure bytearray get packed with bytes of consistent length.... e.g.:

```
>>> len(bytearray(b'\xfdo\xfe\x7f\xfd\xd3\xf1d'))
8
```

Even though I see only 6 bytes represented. The ultimate problem I have with unpacking I'm not sure if each byte is 8 or 16 bit ahead of time, so I don't know what combination of letters to use in the second argument...

So, given the b-string representation, it seems that python DOES have knowledge of the way the bytes are encoded, however it seems like the normal array functions I've got on hand are getting this info from the bytearray. I'm sure there is a pythonic way to parse this bytearray to integers, but I just can't find it...

Any help extremely appreciated

Comment: There are 8, any bytes in the printible ascii range get printed as the corresponding ascii characters, so there's a byte `o` after the first one and `d` at the very end

Comment: Anyway, a byte array is an array of *bytes*, so when you iterate over it, it will be over the 8-bit sections of the buffer. So, you seem to know that you can use `struct.unpack`, what, exactly, is the issue?

Comment: "I'm not sure if each byte is 8 or 16 bit ahead of time" huh? A byte is 8 bits, but you are trying to unpack 16 bits that represent signed integers?

Comment: Maybe I don't get how unpack works, but it seems to require a format string which defines the length of each byte in the sequence. I'm not sure how to infer this from the shape of my `bytearray` (without doing so manually) - perhaps a better question which would help my cause would be "how do I turn my 16-bit bytearray `bytearray(b'\xfdo\xfe\x7f\xfd\xd3\xf1d')` into a sequence of 6 unsigned integers"

Comment: *what do you mean by length of a bytes?* a byte is 8 bits, always.  The format string gives you the format (which includes bitlength) of the type you are trying to create. Anyway, use the `array` method, which takes the same format strings, you just want `import array; array.array('h', raw)` for example, which creates an array of 16-bit signed integers, which I guess is what you want (you haven't been really clear)

Comment: This is perfect! That's what I'm after. My issue was I could either get python to interpret bytes (or words or whatever you call them) as 16 or 8 bits long, but I could not get it to do either. It would either split my 16 bit number into 2 8 bit, or stick 2 of my 8 bit numbers into a 16 bit. I will close this as answered after pointing to your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga for the answer I was looking for. I used the array library which seemed to solve all of my problems:

```
import array
result = array.array('h', raw)
```

Graphing the values output here is the same as the oscilloscope for my audio file.... Cheers!

[integers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldbWr.png)
[oscilloscope of my working .wav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P17pR.png)